# Jackson: Deserialize abstract class

Tags: java, json, jackson, abstract-class, json-deserialization

I'm using Jackson to deserialize several JSON objects that share some properties:

```json
{
  "error": "",
  "result": {
    "RowNumber": "2",
    "Rows": [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Category": "A"
      }, {
        "Id": "2",
        "Category": "A"
      }
    ],
    "__chk": ""
  },
  "request_name": "Method01"
}
```

```json
{
  "error": "",
  "result": {
    "FileName": "00001.xml",
    "__chk": ""
  },
  "request_name": "Method02"
}
```

They share "top level" properties (`error`,`result` and `request_name`), where:

- `request_name` is the property that differentiates JSON objects
- `result` is a different object between the 2 JSON objects

What I'm trying to do is have an abstract class (`AbstractJson`) with `error` and `result` properties:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "request_name")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = JsonMethod01.class, name = "Method01"),
    @Type(value = JsonMethod02.class, name = "Method02") }
)
public abstract class AbstractJson {
    @JsonProperty("error")  private String sError;
    @JsonProperty("result") private AbstractJsonResult oResult;
    
    public String getError() {return sError;}
    public void setError(String sError) {this.sError = sError;}
    
    public AbstractJsonResult getResult() {return oResult;}
    public void setResult(AbstractJsonResult oResult) {this.oResult = oResult;}
}
```

```java
public abstract class AbstractJsonResult {
    @JsonProperty("__chk")  private String sChk;
}
```

```java
public class JsonMethod01 extends AbstractJson {
    public static class JsonResult extends AbstractJsonResult {
        @JsonProperty("RowNumber")  private int iRowNumber;
        @JsonProperty("Rows")       private List<JsonResultRow> oRows;
        
        public int getRowNumber() {return iRowNumber;}
        public void setRowNumber(int iRowNumber) {this.iRowNumber = iRowNumber;}
        
        public List<JsonResultRow> getRows() {return oRows;}
        public void setRows(List<JsonResultRow> oRows) {this.oRows = oRows;}
    }
    
    public static class JsonResultRow {
        @JsonProperty("Id")         private String sId;
        @JsonProperty("Category")   private String sCategory;
        
        public String getId() {return sId;}
        public void setId(String sId) {this.sId = sId;}
        
        public String getCategory() {return sCategory;}
        public void setCategory(String sCategory) {this.sCategory = sCategory;}
    }
}
```

```java
public class JsonMethod02 extends AbstractJson {
    public static class JsonResult extends AbstractJsonResult {
        @JsonProperty("FileName") String sFileName;
        
        public String getFileName() {return sFileName;}
        public void setFileName(String sFileName) {this.sFileName = sFileName;}
    }
}
```

```java
public class Test {
    public static AbstractJson jsonDeserialization(String sJson) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(sJson, AbstractJson.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sMethod01Json = "{\"error\":\"\",\"result\":{\"RowNumber\":\"2\",\"Rows\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Category\":\"A\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Category\":\"A\"}],\"__chk\":\"\"},\"request_name\":\"Method01\"}";
        String sMethod02Json = "{\"error\":\"\",\"result\":{\"FileName\":\"00001.xml\",\"__chk\":\"\"},\"request_name\":\"Method02\"}";
        System.out.println(sMethod01Json);
        System.out.println(sMethod02Json);
        try {
            AbstractJson oJsonMethod01 = jsonDeserialization(sMethod01Json);
            System.out.println(oJsonMethod01);
            AbstractJson oJsonMethod02 = jsonDeserialization(sMethod02Json);
            System.out.println(oJsonMethod02);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

During deserialization I get the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `json.deserialize_abstractclass.esempio02.AbstractJsonResult` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information.
```

I understood that isn't possible to deserialize an abstract class, but searching the net I couldn't find a solution that could fit my needs.

Comment: I don't see `JsonMethod01` override `getResult()` nor do I see any type info on `"result"`, so how should Jackson know it should construct instances of either `JsonResult`?

Comment: You have JsonMethod01 and JsonMethod02. Just follow the contract and use these classes in your test.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand what I should do... could you please give me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have already concrete classes derived from the abstract class: JsonMethod01 and JsonMethod02. Just follow the contract and use these classes in your code. Like this:

```
public class Test {
    private static mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // better to have it as a singleton

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sMethod01Json = "{\"error\":\"\",\"result\":{\"RowNumber\":\"2\",\"Rows\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Category\":\"A\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Category\":\"A\"}],\"__chk\":\"\"},\"request_name\":\"Method01\"}";
        String sMethod02Json = "{\"error\":\"\",\"result\":{\"FileName\":\"00001.xml\",\"__chk\":\"\"},\"request_name\":\"Method02\"}";
        System.out.println(sMethod01Json);
        System.out.println(sMethod02Json);
        try {
            JsonMethod01 oJsonMethod01 = mapper.readValue(sMethod01Json, JsonMethod01.class);
            System.out.println(oJsonMethod01);
            JsonMethod02 oJsonMethod02 = mapper.readValue(sMethod02Json, JsonMethod02.class);
            System.out.println(oJsonMethod02);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error. ```com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `json.deserialize_abstractclass.esempio02.AbstractJsonResult` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information```

Comment: Now I see. The error comes from yet another abstract class you are using: AbstractJsonResult. Any chance to make it just a concrete class? Removing abstract identifier.

Comment: Or otherwise annotate it too with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`.

Comment: @Mar-Z It's the only solution I've found so far.
However, this solution complicates a few things in the rest of the project as I am forced to define 2 different classes for the management of ```result```:
  - ```Method01Result```
  - ```Method02Result```

Both with the same properties (in my example above ```__chk```).
In the next steps of the project I need to test the value of ```__chk``` (regardless if it comes from Method01 or Method02), so I was trying to use the abstract class ```AbstractJsonResult```

Comment: @RobSpoor How could I use annotations? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: But you know that you can extend classes even if they are not abstract? Then you could write the tests using the base class (not abstract).